# C# multidimensional array value changes unexpectedly

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Hello i have a realy strange behavior in this piece of code:

```
public class IGraphics
{
    public  int[,] screen;

    private int[,] world;
    private int[,] entitys;
    private int[,] buffer;

    private int screenW;
    private int screenH;
    public IGraphics(int screenW, int screenH) {

        this.screenH = screenH;
        this.screenW = screenW;
        screen = new int[screenW + 1, screenH];
        buffer = new int[screenW + 1, screenH];


    }
    public void loadWorld(int[,] world) {
        this.world = world;
    }
    public void clear() {
        screen = new int[screenW + 1, screenH];
        world = new int[screenW, screenH];
        for (int y = 0; y < world.GetLength(1); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < world.GetLength(0); x++) {
                world[x, y] = 0;

            }

        }

    }

    private void loadScreen() {


    }
    private void updateEntitys()
    {
        entitys = new int[screenW, screenH];
        List<GameObject> EntRow = Common.world.getEntitys();
        for (int i = 0; i < EntRow.Count(); i++)
        {
            entitys[EntRow[i].x, EntRow[i].y] = EntRow[i].Icon;
        }

    }
    public void draw() {

        updateEntitys();
        for (int y = 0; y < screen.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < screen.GetLength(0) - 1; x++)
            {
                if (entitys[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    screen[x, y] = world[x, y];
                }
                else
                {
                    screen[x, y] = entitys[x, y];

                }
            }

            screen[screen.GetLength(0) - 1, y] = 123;

        }
        if (buffer.Cast<int>().SequenceEqual(screen.Cast<int>()))
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.Clear();
        buffer = screen;
        for (int y = 0; y < screen.GetLength(1); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < screen.GetLength(0); x++) {
                if (screen[x, y] == 123)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else {
                    Console.Write(objectStore.getIcon(screen[x, y]));
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

the problem comes in the Draw() function where i set the value of the screen[,] array for some reason it also change the value of the buffer[,] array before the control also tried moving the buffer[,] in a seperate class but i had the same problem.

Someone as an explanation?

Comment: Uh... perhaps because `buffer = screen;`? I don't think it's strange that the compiler does what you asked it to do.

Comment: i think you intended to "Copy" the screen to buffer, but instead, you assigned buffer the reference of screen, so both variables now point to the same array. Try to instead copy the array using Clone or copy or something. I think its screen.CopyTo

Comment: Agree to the above.  Otherwise, prove to your self (and others) that changing one changes the other by writing a really simple test case to demonstrate.  Then we can better ponder the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a reference variable to another variable, you copy the *pointer* to that variable, instead of copying the content, so what you end up with is two variables that point to the same array.

Try to instead copy the array using Clone or copy or something. I think its screen.CopyTo

```
screen.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the body of the method called `draw`, you will notice this assignment:

```
buffer = screen;
```

This is might the cause of the change you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

See the other answers for possible reasons for your problem.  However, the following code shows that changing screen[] does **not** change buffer[].  This kind of effort on your part would allow you to focus your investigation elsewhere.  The principle is to first simply.

```
    int counter = 1;
    public void draw()
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < screen.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < screen.GetLength(0) - 1; x++)
            {
                screen[x, y] = counter++;
            }
            screen[screen.GetLength(0) - 1, y] = 123;
        }
        if (buffer.Cast<int>().SequenceEqual(screen.Cast<int>()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Help!");
            return;
        }
        // check again
        for (int y = 0; y < screen.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < screen.GetLength(0) - 1; x++)
            {
                if (screen[x, y] == buffer[x, y])
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Help two!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```